# `Ord` instance `on` some function

Tags: haskell, typeclass

I want to write an `Ord` instance for a data type `Foo` which delegates all comparison to a function `bar :: Foo -> Bar` where `Bar` is a data type that has an `Ord` instance available.

If I manually write this instance it looks like:

```
instance Ord Foo where
  compare x y
    | bar x == bar y = EQ
    | bar x <= bar y = LT
    | otherwise      = GT
```

Is there a more concise way to write this?

---

In Scala (with Scalaz), I can write:

```
 implicit val FooOrder: Order[Foo] = Order[Bar] contramap bar
```

Does Haskell have anything similar?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
import Data.Ord

instance Ord Foo where
    compare = comparing bar
```

is the most concise version I can think of OTTOMH.

Slightly less concise, but better to generalise is

```
import Data.Function

instance Ord Foo where
    compare = compare `on` bar
```

Comment: Good enough for me. Thank you! :-) I would like to know though how such cases are dealt with in general.

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail what you mean with "such cases"? There is the very useful `Data.Function.on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c`, which you could use to define ``compare = compare `on` bar`` in the above situation. That can be used in more general settings than `comparing`.

Comment: By "such cases" I meant all typeclasses for whom contravariance applies. `Ord` has only one function, but some typeclasses might have more, or might define their contravariance relation in ways specific to them.

Comment: I am accepting this answer because it satisfies my immediate need. Thank you again!

Comment: Aha. Well, I don't know if there's a generally followed practice if you need to go beyond `on`, but for most cases, that's enough.